# Subtracting elements in an array

Tags: java

I want to obtain the difference between the elements inside the array, say `[1,2,3,4,5]`, how would I go about that? Currently I have:

```
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    diff -= args[i];
}
```

Expected output

```
1-2-3-4-5 = -13
```

Actual output

```
-1-2-3-4-5 = -15
```

Comment: Are you setting `diff = args[0]` before the loop?

Comment: **Unable to reproduce**. The array is 5 long, but the loop skips the first value, so it is impossible to get `-13` or `-15` as a result, but I guess that depend on how `diff` is initialized.

Comment: @StaticBeagle I had it initialized to 0. I tried it again but `diff = args[1]` before the loop as I have a string operator there and I just parse there. I want to simply enter the arguments in command line, something like `java runThis - 1 2 3 4 5` I'm getting -14 now as the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when running the code below, I'm getting the expected output of -13. perhaps your error is elsewhere

```java
int[] args = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int diff = args[0];
    
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
  diff -= args[i];
}

System.out.println(diff);
```

Comment: I figured it out. My diff was initialized to `args[1]` as I intended, but I also needed to change `int = 1` to `int = 2`, not exactly sure why that is yet.

Comment: i think its because the 0th argument is the command itself, while the next arguments (1 .. n) are the actual int values you're looking to loop over

Answer (score 0):

You can try, output -13 (JavaScript)

```
 let dataArray=[1,2,3,4,5];
  console.log(dataArray.reduce((r,sub)=>r-sub));
```

For Java you can start your loop from the second position:

```
int diff = args[0];
    
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
  diff -= args[i];
}
```